# Alarm Manager response to notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

i have an alarm set up to trigger every day, my problem is that, i will have two buttons in the notification, the put off button, and the i got it button.

How i'm doing

Code to set up the alarm:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 38);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_reciever.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Code in the reciever:

Consulta_Tratamento consulta_tratamento = new Consulta_Tratamento();

String remedio = consulta_tratamento.getMedicamento();
    String dose = consulta_tratamento.getDosagem();

```
PendingIntent pTomei = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, actMarcaCon.class),0);
PendingIntent pAdiar = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, actMarcaCon.class),0);

Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("MHS")
        .setContentText(/*Colocar nome do usuário*/"Esta na Hora de Tomar Seu Remédio:" + remedio +
                " /n dosagem:" + dose)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250, 100, 500})
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_adiar, "Adiar", pAdiar)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_tomei, "Tomei", pTomei)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

if(intent!=null) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}


NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

My problem is that, in the add action method, i can only pass and pendingIntent, not an method, so how can i make my button call an method instead of an intent?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make my button call an method instead of an intent?

You can't.

Set an "extra" in the `Intent` that you use to create the `PendingIntent`. In `onCreate()` and/or `onNewIntent()` check for the presence of the "extra" in the `Intent` and use that as a trigger to call the method.